# Match function seems to be returning from within a formula?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, vlookup, spreadsheet, flatten

I am using this formula to find the relative position of the **furthest right** word "Move" in my cells.

```
=MATCH("Move",AG5:LM5,1)
```

The only problem is the cells in AG5:LM5 are using this formula:

```
=IF(LEFT(KV5,3)="Map","Move",FALSE)
```

The match function always seems to return the relative position of the farthest right entry, even if the farthest right entry is "FALSE".

Is there a way to fix this?

**Edit:**

Here is an example sheet:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/15idQ0s3ljoPSroSPi-Rv-Dhh_Nm88Rj9hB8WmNdCYjI/edit?usp=sharing

For **Test1** I want the location column to ignore the **Recruit** input and instead return the **Map7.8** input. In **Test2** I want it to pull the rightmost instance with "Map" in the input into the location column, this is acting as intended.

Comment: I think it would be better if you could provide a minimal example of what you currently have so that we can check the input and the desired output to understand the full behavior of whats currently happening and what you actually need.

Comment: I included an example spreadsheet and described what I want to occur.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should be using:

```
=MATCH("Move", AG5:LM5, 0)
```

---

### update

delete everything in range C3:C and use this in C3:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(ROW(D3:D1000), QUERY(SORT(SPLIT(
 FLATTEN(ROW(D3:D1000)&"×"&COLUMN(D3:3)&"×"&
 IF(REGEXMATCH(D3:1000&"", "Map"), D3:1000, )), "×"), 1, 1, 2, ), 
 "where Col3 contains 'Map'"), 3, )))
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry should've been more clear in the question. Edited for clarity. 

I am looking for the relative position of the rightmost instance of "Move" in the range

Comment: @plerpsandplerps answer updated

Comment: this is working just like I wanted it to! thanks so much!